# Android drawable selection

Tags: android, android-drawable

Lets say I have an image image.png in drawable, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi. In case if I run the app in an xxhdpi device which image would be taken up by the device?

Comment: My bet on drawable.

Comment: Drawable image will be taken up.

Answer (score 1):

> If no matching resource is available, the system uses the default
>   resource and scales it up or down as needed to match the current
>   screen size and density
>
> The "default" resources are those that are not tagged with a
>   configuration qualifier. For example, the resources in drawable/ are
>   the default drawable resources.

For more detail go to [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Answer (score 0):

The Arnis's answer is correct, but not complete.

The generic rule is that Android system looks for a "match" for the requested resource, but this actually doesn't mean that if it can't find a specific resource size it will use the "default" resource. Indeed the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) says:

> When the system is looking for a density-specific resource and does
>   not find it in the density-specific directory, it won't always use the
>   default resources. The system may instead use one of the other
>   density-specific resources in order to provide better results when
>   scaling.

So, answering the question, on a xxhdpi device, probably Android will look for the "closer" (in terms of resolution) resource.